# using an array function for click events

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created symbols which contain animations (mc1 - mc25). I would like to play these animations if I click on the symbols (click on mc1 -> play mc1, click on mc2 -> play mc2 etc.).

I created an array to address all my symbols in one go. It works ok.

```
var A:Array = [mc1, mc2, mc3, mc4,...mc25] // create array
car aClip:MovieClip;

for each (aClip in A) // stop all symbols
{aClip.stop();}
```

How can I get to the result below for all my symbols using an array function?

```
mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_4);
function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
mc1.play();
}
```

I tried something like this but I couldn't get it work:

```
aClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
aClip.play();
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way about it is to algorithmically figure which one was clicked. The script below is short and does not contain various checks, it assumes all the elements of **A** are really **MovieClip**s.

```
// Assume, you filled the Array with these clips already.
var A:Array;

// Iterate all the clips.
for each (var aClip:MovieClip in A)
{
    // Subscribe to each of the clips for the CLICK event.
    aClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPlay);
}

// Click event handler function. The point is, you can subscribe it
// to the multiple objects and use the function argument to figure out
// which one of them all is actually the source of the event.
// Furthermore, you can subscribe it to handle multiple events too,
// the argument also carries the id of the event. Sometimes it is
// really simpler to compose a single event-processing gate
// rather then process each one event in a separate handler.
function clickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Use e.currentTarget because the initial e.target
    // could be not the MovieClip itself, but some interactive
    // element deep inside the MovieClip's hierarchy.

    // Read about bubbling events (MouseEvent is bubbling)
    // to get the whole picture of it.

    // Typecasting, because e.target and e.currentTarget
    // are of base Object type.
    var aClip:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    // Well, the only thing that is left.
    aClip.play();
}
```

Comment: @ Organis - thanks for the code and the explanation. Much appreciated!